# Could we have guidance on the closure question update notifications?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, new-users

[image: ![enter image description here]

I recently had a question closed, then reopened and I was pleasantly surprised that I was given a notification of its closure and reopening.

As an experienced user, particularly on meta, I probably get the subtle dynamics of the community and the mechanics of the question lifecycle better.

It might be useful to 'organically' link to guidance on question improvement for folks new to the site - closures are often a reason for contention and friction and this seems like a great opportunity to educate.